# Why is IntoIter not owning the values?

Tags: types, rust, ownership

I want to iterate over the bytes of an integer:

```rust
use core::mem::size_of;

const SIZE: usize = size_of::<u64>();
    
fn main() {
    let x: u64 = 512;
    let mut buf: [u8; SIZE] = [0; SIZE];
    
    for (i, b) in x.to_be_bytes().into_iter().enumerate() {              
        buf[i] = b;
    }
}
```

The compiler tells me for the line `buf[i] = b;` that he `` expected `u8`, found `&u8` `` . But why?

When I take a look at the implementation of the `IntoIterator` trait for the owned array type `[T; N]` the `into_iter()` method returns a `std::array::IntoIter<T, N>` which implements the `Iterator` trait where `type Item = T`. Shouldn't `T` evaluate to `u8` here?

Why is the iterator returning `&u8` references instead of owned `u8` bytes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Rust documentation mentions this behavior for `array`:

> Prior to Rust 1.53, arrays did not implement IntoIterator by value, so the method call `array.into_iter()` auto-referenced into a slice iterator. Right now, the old behavior is preserved in the 2015 and 2018 editions of Rust for compatibility, ignoring `IntoIterator` by value. In the future, the behavior on the 2015 and 2018 edition might be made consistent to the behavior of later editions.

- [Rust documentation, "Primitive Type array"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#editions)

You will get references if you're using Rust `2018`, but for the time being you can use `IntoIterator::into_iter(array)`

Dereferencing the `b` within the loop will hint at this:

```
  |
9 |     for (i, b) in x.to_be_bytes().into_iter().enumerate() {
  |                                   ^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(array_into_iter)]` on by default
  = warning: this changes meaning in Rust 2021
  = note: for more information, see issue #66145 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/66145>
```

Here's an example:

```rust
use core::mem::size_of;

const SIZE: usize = size_of::<u64>();

fn main() {
    let x: u64 = 512;
    let mut buf: [u8; SIZE] = [0; SIZE];

    for (i, b) in IntoIterator::into_iter(x.to_be_bytes()).enumerate() {
        buf[i] = b;
    }
}
```

- [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5b282eab764b16c9b0495f84289b02d7)

---

The Rust 2021 edition, with the new behavior, will likely land this October. See [Rust Blog, "The Plan for the Rust 2021 Edition"](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/05/11/edition-2021.html) for more information.

Comment: rust 1.56 should be stable for edition 2021